# Select with a ExecuteScalar() not working when i use a variable, always return empty, when i don't use variable it works - C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, variables, executescalar

When I use a variable, the result of `command.ExecuteScalar()` it's always empty (blank), I'm not receiving any error messages, just a blank value,
but when I use the same SQL query without using a variable it works.

What I have tried so far:

```cs
//variable @num is a long and contais the value = '8131818060'              

string teste = num.ToString();


// 1º: In this case ip value: it's empty

string sql = @"select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = '" + teste + "'";

command = new SqlCommand(sql, con.conectar());
var ip = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
con.desconectar();
MessageBox.Show("IP Value: " + ip);


// 2º: In this case ip value: it's empty

string sql = @"select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = " + teste;

command = new SqlCommand(sql, con.conectar());
var ip = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
con.desconectar();
MessageBox.Show("IP Value: " + ip);


// 3º: In this case ip value: it's empty

string sql = @"select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = " + num";

command = new SqlCommand(sql, con.conectar());
var ip = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
con.desconectar();
MessageBox.Show("IP Value: " + ip);


// 4º In this case ip value: it's empty

string sql = @"select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = @e164";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con.conectar());
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e164", teste);

//string ip = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
var ip = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

MessageBox.Show("IP Value:: " + ip);
con.desconectar();


// 5º In this case ip value: it's empty

string sql = @"select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = @e164";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con.conectar());
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@e164",
    Value = teste,
}
);

//string ip = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
var ip = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

MessageBox.Show("IP Value: " + ip);
con.desconectar();


//6º This one it's the only way it works
// That's the only way it works, When i write the parameter = "8131818060"

string sql = "select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = 8131818060";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con.conectar());

string IP = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

MessageBox.Show("IP Value: " + IP);

//The ip values in this case is "10.101.1.0"
```

E164 is a nvarchar(10)

I've made a test and result 1 is true, so teste is equal to "8131818060"
But result2 is false, "sql" is not equal to "sql2"

```
        bool result1 = string.Equals(teste,"8131818060");





        string sql = "select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = 8131818060";


        string sql2 = "select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = " + teste;


        bool result2 = string.Equals(sql,"sql2");
```

//following Roeland suggestion
             //I tested that way, and i'm reciving a NullReferenceException error on ip.ToString()
             //System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
         //num is a long variable pass from the user

         string sql = @"select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = '" + num.ToString() + "'";
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con.conectar());
         var ip = command.ExecuteScalar();
         con.desconectar();
         MessageBox.Show("IP Value: " + ip.ToString());
```

Comment: What is the table data type of the `E164` column? I suggest you [avoid AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and specify the parameter type that matches the column data type.

Comment: A couple of your examples are clearly wrong because you put the variable name instead of value into the sql statement. Make `teste` an `int` or `long` instead of string and assign the correct `SqlDbType` to your parameter.

Comment: The datatype of E164 its a nvarchar(10)

Comment: Then I don't think `teste == "8131818060"`. The only way the code you have shown and the output you have described could be true is if the value of `teste` is not what you think it is. Your comment mentions `@num` (emphasis on the @) which looks suspicious. Did you look at the runtime value of `teste` at that point in the code? Examples 1, 4 and 5 should work. Your last example works because you have hard-coded the correct value (though you are forcing an implicit cast which is inefficient).

Comment: I've made a test and result 1 is true, so teste is equal to "8131818060"
   
   
   bool result1 = string.Equals(teste,"8131818060");
   
   
   But result2 is false, "sql" is not equal to "sql2"
   
   
   string sql = "select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = 8131818060";


   string sql2 = "select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = " + teste;
   
   
   bool result2 = string.Equals(sql,"sql2");

Comment: Of course `sql1` is not equal to the string literal "sql2".

Comment: any suggestion on how ExecuteScalar() can return the correct value?

Comment: To prevent SQL injection, please always use parameters, do not build a value into a command string

Answer (score 1):

I tried this example code:

```
long test = 8131818060;
string sql = @"select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = '" + test.ToString() + "'";
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    InitialCatalog = "xxx",
    DataSource = @"127.0.0.1\V2016",
    UserID = "xxx",
    Password = "xxx"
};
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
var ip = command.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("IP Value: " + ip.ToString());
```

Along with this SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblRamais](
    [E164] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Sites_IP_Rede] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblRamais2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [E164] ASC
)
) 
INSERT INTO tblRamais SELECT '8131818060','10.101.1.0'
```

The code did return the value of 10.101.1.0

So your first try should be OK.

Your second example will fail if there is any record where column E164 has a non numeric value.

In your third try, this line won't compile:

```
string sql = @"select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = " + num";
```

Your fourth and fifth try are OK too.

When I encounter problems like these, I alway use the SQL Profiler to check the statement SQL Server executed.

Comment: //I tested that way, and i'm reciving a NullReferenceException error on ip.ToString()
    //System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    
    //num is a long variable pass from the user
    
    string sql = @"select Sites_IP_Rede from tblRamais where E164 = '" + num.ToString() + "'";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conex.conectar());
    var ip = command.ExecuteScalar();
    conex.desconectar();
    MessageBox.Show("IP Value: " + ip.ToString());

Comment: Hi José, is it possible to use the SQL Profiler to check what statement SQL Server executes? If so, check if this statement looks OK and see what happens when you paste it into SSMS.If you get a NullReferenceException, than no record was found. Did you check Crowcoders comment. Try bool result2 = string.Equals(sql,sql2);

Comment: Roeland thank you again. I didn't even know that you could do a trace in sql, after i use the SQL Profiler, i saw tha the statement was arriving correctly. The problem  was that i was doing a delete of the data before the query, and i wanted to do the other way around. It was such a stupiety of mine. i'm really sorry for all the trouble.  my apologies. Problem solved.